# Initialising the logger in each and every class in java of sl4j

Tags: java, slf4j

'

I am using sl4j for  logging in my java classes although I have added the dependency too, my question is that if I have lots of java classes say a count of 50 classes in different packages, then for logging do I need to add the below statement in my every class, rite now suppose below code is for my main class is

```
final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
```

Is there any way through which I do not need to initialize the logger of sl4j in each and every class explicitly

Comment: Is there a reason why you can’t just make it static and refer to it from the other classes?

Comment: @vandench My point of view is there are lots of java classes in my project which will continue to grow further so I want it to configure globally

Comment: If you want it to configure globally then you probably want a static variable in one of your classes that is referenced from everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use the following code.

```
final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
```

It is required because, all the log statements are specific to specific classes and methods for log analysis. If we create a separate alternative to the above statement, then also we need to define in each class. Think of a situation, we have `System.out.println` statement which we write everywhere for analysis. Can we think of alternative to the above ? I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is spring based, you can use AOP to log the messages.